# Independent table row spacing

Tags: tables, spacing

I have created a fairly simple table using `booktabs`:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{ p{5cm} | p{5cm} }
    \toprule
    \textbf{Primäre Quellen} & \textbf{Sekundäre Quellen} \\
    Jira              &  exply \\
    Confluence        &  Canias ERP \\
    E-Mail            &  Diverse Excel-Tabellen (Vertrieb, Verwaltung) \\
    Nextcloud         & \\
    Rocket.Chat       & \\
    GitLab/GitHub     & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
    \label{table:informationsquellen}
    \caption{Primäre und sekundäre Quellen bei XXXXXX}
\end{table}
```

Currently, the rows are "aligned": 
[image]
I want to remove the alignment, making the columns independent of each other (effectively removing the green outlined space).

Is this possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Than make only one cell in each column and use `\par` to move text in new line or inserts empty lines between text formed  paragraphs.

Comment: Why use a table at all if the two columns are not related? Wouldn't a list like enumerate or itemize serve the same purpose without the reader wondering if there is a correlation between the columns or not? Please also note, that booktabs horizontal lines are not compatible with vertical lines (hence the small gaps in the vertical lines).

Comment: If you want to stay with a table, why not simply use two `l` type columns? The table should still fit into the textwidth of a standard article even without linebreaks in the cells.

Comment: Off-topic but nevertheless important: the `\label` directive ***must*** be placed after the associated `\caption` directive. Otherwise, cross-references to the `table` cannot be correct.

Comment: I want to use a table because a: a list is not as easy on the eyes, but hard to ignore inside a block of text and b: the table is supposed to be fairly small, floating somewhere so the reader can look it up if he wants to, but does not have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a `tabular` containing only one row, and break lines inside a cell using either `\par` as shown below, or `\newline`. As leandriis [warned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsgIn.png), horizontal lines created by commands from the `booktabs` package aren't designed to join well with vertical lines (the author of [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) explains in the manual of his great package that vertical lines in tables are almost always a bad typographic choice: both ugly and useless).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\begin{tabular}{ p{5cm} | p{5cm} }
  \toprule
  \textbf{Primäre Quellen}\par
  Jira\par
  Confluence\par
  E-Mail\par
  Nextcloud\par
  Rocket.Chat\par
  GitLab/GitHub &
  \textbf{Sekundäre Quellen}\par
  exply\par
  Canias ERP\par
  Diverse Excel-Tabellen (Vertrieb, Verwaltung)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

You can get a nicer layout by removing the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`, using a dedicated row for the table header, finishing it with `\\\midrule` and suppressing the vertical rule. As per leandriis' suggestion, I also added `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` in front of the second column specification in the `tabular` preamble, so that interword spacing in the second column doesn't get overstretched (this way, it is not stretched at all; as a consequence, the right side of the second column is allowed to have a “ragged” appearance, which doesn't change much here since we were ending lines/paragraphs manually anyway). The `>{...}` syntax requires the `array` package, hence we are adding it too.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{5cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash} p{5cm} }
  \toprule
  \textbf{Primäre Quellen} & \textbf{Sekundäre Quellen}\\
  \midrule
  Jira\par
  Confluence\par
  E-Mail\par
  Nextcloud\par
  Rocket.Chat\par
  GitLab/GitHub &
  exply\par
  Canias ERP\par
  Diverse Excel-Tabellen (Vertrieb, Verwaltung)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

You could also do that using `multicols` (possibly inside a `minipage`) and/or `enumitem`. There are many possibilities.

P.S.: as Mico [said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503376/independent-table-row-spacing/503380#comment1271512_503376), if you use `\caption` and `\label`, be sure to put `\label` *after* the associated `\caption`, because it is `\caption` that increases the counter (`\label` uses the last reference set with `\refstepcounter`)!

Comment: You might want to consider adding `\raggedright\arraybackslash` to the second `p` type column to prevent the large white spaces (e.g. between "Diverse" and  "Excel-Tabellen").

Comment: @leandriis I agree and used your suggestion in the second example. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use two distinct `tabular` environments for the columns:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
\textbf{Primäre Quellen} & \textbf{Sekundäre Quellen} \\
\midrule
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}@{}}
  Jira \\
  \addlinespace
  Confluence \\
  \addlinespace
  E-Mail \\
  \addlinespace
  Nextcloud \\
  \addlinespace
  Rocket.Chat \\
  \addlinespace
  GitLab/GitHub \\
  \end{tabular}
&
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}@{}}
  exply \\
  \addlinespace
  Canias ERP \\
  \addlinespace
  Diverse Excel-Tabellen (Vertrieb, Verwaltung) \\
  \end{tabular}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Primäre und sekundäre Quellen bei XXXXXX}
\label{table:informationsquellen}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be careful that `\label` should go *after* `\caption`. Using `\arraystretch` yields not very nice spaces, better using `\addlinespace` where needed.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the material in the two columns from interacting, you could place it into separate subordinated `tabular` environments. In the following solution, the "outer" `tabular` environment consists of two `l` columns; the outer environment is needed solely for the `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` directives. The "inner" `tabular` environments each contain a single `p` column, which allows automatic line-breaking (if needed).

I would also omit the vertical divider line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\footnotesize % is this really needed?
\begin{tabular}{ ll }  % "outer" tabular
  \toprule
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} p{5cm} @{}} % first "inner" tabular
    \textbf{Primäre Quellen} \\
    Jira        \\                  
    Confluence  \\              
    E-Mail      \\                             
    Nextcloud   \\               
    Rocket.Chat \\            
    GitLab/GitHub 
  \end{tabular} &          
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} p{5cm} @{}} % second "inner" tabular
    \textbf{Sekundäre Quellen} \\
    exply      \\
    Canias ERP \\
    Diverse Excel-Tabellen (Vertrieb, Verwaltung) 
  \end{tabular}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Primäre und sekundäre Quellen bei XXXXXX}
\label{table:informationsquellen}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `\\ ` seems to be missing after `\textbf{Primäre Quellen}`.

Comment: @leandriis - Thanks! Will fix right away.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion using two `itemize` environments instead of the `tabular`. If placed inside of a `table` this can float, get a cpation and be referenced as usual:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{3.5cm}
  \textbf{Primäre Quellen}
  \begin{itemize}[label={--}]
  \item Jira
  \item Confluence
  \item E-Mail
  \item Nextcloud
  \item Rocket.Chat
  \item GitLab/GitHub 
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}\raggedright
  \textbf{Sekundäre Quellen}
  \begin{itemize}[label={--}]
  \item exply
  \item Canias ERP
  \item Diverse Excel-Tabellen (Vertrieb, Verwaltung)\\
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Primäre und sekundäre Quellen bei XXXXXX}\label{table:informationsquellen}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```